# Django httpresponse stripping CR

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

When I open my text file attachment that is generated using the below code, the HTTP response always seems to strip out the CR from each line, the users of this file will be using Notepad so I need CR/LF on each line.

```
the_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b') 
<procedure call to generate lines of text in "the_file">
the_file.seek(0)
filestring = the_file.read()
response = HttpResponse(filestring,
    mimetype="text/plain")
response['Content-Length'] = the_file.tell()
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="4cos_example.txt"' 
return response
```

If I use this method, I get CR/LF in my files but I'd like to avoid having to write the file to disk at all, so it doesn't seem to be a good solution:

```
the_file = open('myfile.txt','w+')
<procedure call to generate lines of text in "the_file">
the_file.close
the_file = open('myfile.txt','rb')
filestring = the_file.read()
response = HttpResponse(filestring,
    mimetype="text/plain")
response['Content-Length'] = the_file.tell()
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="4cos_example.txt"' 
return response
```

I feel like the solution should be obvious. but I can't close a tempfile and re-open it in binary mode (preserving the CR/LR). Heck I'm not even sure i'm in the right ballpark regarding how to correctly do this :) None the less, I'd like to pass this data as an attachment to the user after the configuration is assembled and have it display correctly in notepad. Is tempfile the wrong solution here or is there a mechanic of tempfile that will solve this issue for me without having to use file IO on disk.

Comment: Why are you using TemporaryFile? You write to it and then read the whole thing. It doesn't seem like you are getting much.

Comment: really, its more an artifact of starting my project as a script that built a configuration file. as I webified the script I didn't need to write the file to disk anymore and instead served the config via httpresponse as a text attachment. I'd certainly like to get rid of the file all together, but working backwards, i was trying to identify why i was loosing CR/LF and left with LF. Regardless, the CR/LF issue still presents a problem unless I open file as binary and serve it that way.

Comment: The Magic seems to be when I close the file, then re-open it  as 'rb'. Is there a way to replicate this behavior with a string instead of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `TemporaryFile`, just use `HttpResponse`:

```
response = HttpResponse('', content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="4cos_example.txt"'
response.write('first line\r\n')
response.write('second line\r\n')    
return response
```

FYI, if this is a very large response, you can also use [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse). But only do that if required, since headers like `Content-Length` will not be able to be added automatically.

Comment: This worked perfectly. No intermediary file and CR/LF on the receiving end like I needed. Thank you so much. response.write was not something I had considered :)